# Dose Remodeling reset a Ship Girl's Level?

Tags: kantai-collection

I am currently building [Samidare's](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Samidare) level to 20 so i can Remodel her to her Kai form. However looking at the other Ship Girls some of them with their Kai form have a separate number like with [Chitose](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Chitose).

I am wondering, When i remodel does a Ship Girl's level reset or do they remain at the level i remodeled them at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from Remodeling Samidare her level did not reset so her Kai form was ta Level 20, however as the Wiki warns about Remodeling all the stats i gained from Modernization were lost.

Comment: All you said is correct except the luck stat. All modernisation to the luck stat  is not lost during modernisation.